# Zenity progress dialog and child processes

Tags: bash, progress-bar, zenity

Let's assume we have a bash script `bash.sh` and a python script `python.py`. The python script can't be modified. (Say, upstream)

`bash.sh` is a zenity wrapper script which creates the gui. `python.py` calls `wget` somewhere at the end.

In `bash.sh` there's `python.py` called and a zenity progress bar displayed, like this

```
./python.py | zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close
```

So the calls are:`bash.sh` => `python.py` => `wget`

If I click "cancel" before the wget download begins, it is canceled and the `python.py` script exits, like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python.py", line 41, in <module>
print(s.encode('utf-8')) IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

But if the wget download starts, clicking "cancel" does absolutely nothing. The progress dialog stays open, nothing is closed.

What should I do, so that the "cancel" button stops the wget download?

Answer (score 0):

I've just published an article explaining how to really kill all children processes when you cancel a zenity progress dialog.

It is available at http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/331-linux-cancel-zenity-progress-dialog-right-way

It should provide you a simple solution to solve this issue.

Cheers.

Comment: And what if two instances of a program are running? It isn't failsafe then.